# Switch Prestashop Language programmatically

Tags: prestashop

I have got a module, that uses displayTop hook for some actions. after that i would like to switch language to desired that exists in the system. I found a method `Tools::switchLanguage` but I can't figure out how to use it properly. any clues?

Comment: what do you mean by `switch language to desired that exists in the system` ? Change to one of the language that is activated in the back office?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a module that already does that: `blocklanguages`. So you can either use this module or take a look at the code to see how it's done. It's pretty easy so you can implement that wherever you want.